# adding the keyboard events using the addEcent Listener

Tags: javascript

i am using el-pagination by element UI and i want to the @keyup.enter & @keyup@space events to it, right now we do not have any kind of key event to it

i am trying to create an addeventlistenber but i am not sure how it should work, i added some code but that does not seems to be working, if anyone has an idea how to fix it, please share

here is my try

```
document.querySelector('.el-pagination').addEventListener('@key.enter',function(e) {
  what should i write here i am have no clue, 
});
```

should i write it on the el-input element inside the el-pagination or where exactly

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like `@key.enter` in `javascript`. You can use either `keyup` or `keydown` event listener for `.el-pagination`.

After that you have to check for event key, whether it is `"Enter"`, `"Space"` etc. You can this by `.key` method.

```
document.querySelector('.el-pagination').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.key === "Enter" || e.key === "Space") {
    //Your code here
  }
});
```